"Alexa Datastore REST API returns 'INVALID_DEVICE' when updating APL template"
I am trying to develop a custom Alexa skill that dynamically updates the data in an APL document using the Datastore REST API. However, the API call is failing, and the APL template is not being updated dynamically.
I have already enabled Datastore permissions in the developer console, and I am testing the skill in both the simulator and on an Echo Show device.
Expected Result: Dynamically update the APL template using Datastore API.
Actual Result: The Datastore API returns the following error:
{
    "results": [
        {
            "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AMARQEYODZRQPA6H453EOAXDX24MHQRY4WFGAA7GNVUXVG2HCNHPNEFHBWBP3PIEMCOOVWZU2435SU2SX4MSAVRELRGQWKAZVJNOWBBGRGXAFREQV7C3VFGRSFWVXAKQ23CDZTSAQM5FTUJRYXKAUHPOZBUH4S6PCABTKBHUAXNXW54QJBFZULNVHTZGP5YUL7UOQ4G6NMJCCNWA",
            "type": "INVALID_DEVICE",
            "message": "The device does not have any package from this skill"
        }
    ]
}


My Code: Below is my implementation of the Datastore REST API call:
async function updateDatastore(token, commands, target) {
    console.log("Datastore Payload:", JSON.stringify({
        commands: commands,
        target: target
    }, null, 2));

    const config = {
        method: "post",
        url: `https://api.fe.amazonalexa.com/v1/datastore/commands`,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `${token.token_type} ${token.access_token}`
        },
        data: {
            commands: commands,
            target: target
        }
    };

    return axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Datastore Response:", JSON.stringify(response.data));
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}


Steps I've Taken:

Verified that the deviceId is fetched correctly and matches the target device.
Tested on both the Alexa simulator and an Echo Show device.
Ensured that the APL and Datastore permissions are enabled in the developer console.
Verified that the token being passed is valid.

Questions:

What does the "INVALID_DEVICE" error mean in this context?
Is there a specific setup required for the device to accept updates via the Datastore REST API?
Are there any common issues with the target or commands when updating APL templates dynamically?

